# add observe to json file if there's new data

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

Well I'm try to build simple chat that receive the message from JSON file

So I think that I should update my function every second to check if there is new message or not, but I think this is not right because it increases the amount of useless request.

This is my code

I use these libraries

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
```

This is my function

```
func didchat(){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.elofight.com/test.json").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        self.reciveResponse = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
        print(self.reciveResponse)
    }
}
```

and this is my function that call this json file every 1 sec

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewChatViewController.didchat), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

any suggest for that ?

Comment: You could use Notification to notify your app that you have new messages.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a minimum time interval as you did, and it's correct.
Or you can use `Firebase`, it does exactly what you mean: you can set your object as listener on the database and you can do something when this happens.

Here you can find a `chat-app` example by Firebase guys: https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example